# Circumflex orm doesn't work with Play 2.1

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1, circumflex-orm

I've updated the play framework to version 2.1 in my application and it don't work more.

Here is a simple controller:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import models.Country
import ru.circumflex.orm._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {

      val co = Country AS "co"
      val q = SELECT (co.*) FROM (co)

      val countries: Seq[Country] = q.list()

      Ok(views.html.index(countries))
  }

}
```

And here is model of a country:

```
package models

import ru.circumflex.orm.{TextField, Table, Record}
import java.util.regex.Pattern

class Country extends Record[String, Country] {
  def PRIMARY_KEY = code
  def relation = Country

  def this(code: String, name: String) = {
    this()
    this.code := code
    this.name := name
  }

  val code: TextField[Country] = "code".VARCHAR(2).NOT_NULL
  val name = "name".TEXT.NOT_NULL

  def cities = inverseMany(City.country)

  override def toString = name.getOrElse("unknow")
}

object Country extends Country with Table[String, Country] {
  val codeKey = UNIQUE(code)
  val codeChk = CONSTRAINT("code_chk").CHECK("code IN ('ch', 'us', 'uk', 'fr', 'es', 'it', 'pt', 'by')")
  val idx = "country_code_idx".INDEX("LOWER(code)").USING("btree").UNIQUE

  validation.notNull(_.code)
            .notEmpty(_.code)
            .pattern(_.code, Pattern.compile("(?i:[a-z]{2})"))
}
```

When page is opened I get a follow error:

```
[error] application -                                                                            

! @6d9l5j0i0 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->                                           

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitial
izerError]]                                                                                      
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]  
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]  
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(
PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:314) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]                                      
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(
PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:312) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]                                      
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play
_2.10.jar:2.1.0]                                                                                 
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play
_2.10.jar:2.1.0]                                                                                 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError                                
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:222) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]     
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$
6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]                                                 
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$
6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]                                                 
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]   
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.sc
ala:108) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]                                                                  
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.sc
ala:106) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]                                                                  
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null                                           
        at controllers.Application$$anonfun$index$1.apply(Application.scala:18) ~[na:na]         
        at controllers.Application$$anonfun$index$1.apply(Application.scala:11) ~[na:na]         
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Action.scala:254) ~[play_2.10.jar:2
.1.0]                                                                                            
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Action.scala:254) ~[play_2.10.jar:2
.1.0]                                                                                            
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:217) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]     
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$
6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]                                                 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: models.Country                                      
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_09]                          
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_09]                          
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_09]             
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_09]                      
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_09]                        
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: The exception suggests that models.Country is not being compiled or is not in the classpath.

Comment: Play 2.1 moved to Scala 2.10 from 2.9.x.  Are you using a circumflex library compiled against 2.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using these info: [reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/circumflex-scala/ne-fkznMLew)

First take last version of circumflex from Github:

```
git clone git://github.com/inca/circumflex.git
```

Following the suggestion, change line in the file orm/src/main/scala/relation.scala

line 55:

```
val _recordClass: Class[R] = Class.forName(
```

**to**

```
val _recordClass: Class[R] = this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(
```

Now we can compile it, install and use in our Play 2.1 App

```
cd circumflex
mvn clean install
```

in case you need only one module:

```
cd circumflex
mvn clean install -pl <circumflex-orm> -am
```

Now edit your `project/Build.scala` file to add dependency and local rep

```
  val appDependencies = Seq(    
   "pro.savant.circumflex" % "circumflex-orm" % "3.1-SNAPSHOT"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(defaultScalaSettings:_*).settings(
    resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file:"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Circumflex 2.x doesnt appear to be built against scala 2.10 (which is needed for play 2.1).

The circumflex 3.0 is being built in 2.10, but its current only in snapshot. 
You can get the snapshot here:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

Note that the package names have changed from **ru.circumflex** to **pro.savant.circumflex** so you may need to refactor your import statements.

Comment: It didn't help =( I gets the same error.

But what’s most interesting is all tests passed succefully.